# Special Characters are improperly unescaped on the stackexchange.com Profile Inbox

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com

Go to your [StackExchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/) profile inbox and have a look at the replies. Notice something?

For example:

> **How do I remove individual autofill suggestions from Google Chrome?**
> haha I`&#39;`d re-add it if I could be anonymous. ;)

[image]

It works in the other tabs though, for example in "Activity".

Comment: Chrome Dev on OS X

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good catch – this is fixed now.

I introduced this bug when converting the Inbox view to [Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx) a couple weeks ago.